# Swiftで配列の中に入れた辞書データの効率的な取り出し方

Tags: ios, swift

質問：配列の中に格納した辞書から効率的にデータを取り出す方法を教えてください。

下記のように様々な型のデータが入った辞書が１０個程度あり、それらを配列として格納したtestArrayがあります。

```
let webview0 = UIWindow()
let webview1 = UIWindow()
let webview2 = UIWindow()

let dic0 = ["name": "yuichi", "string": "test1", "number": 2, "web": webview0]
let dic1 = ["name": "kato", "string": "test2", "number": 5, "web": webview1]
let dic2 = ["name": "max", "string": "test3", "number": 8, "web": webview2]

let testArray = [dic0, dic1, dic2]
```

ここからからnameだけ取り出したい場合、現状は下記のようにループで回して値を取得しているのですが、何か回りくどい気がしています。もっと良いやり方があれば教えていただけないでしょうか。

```
var newArray = [AnyObject]()
for(var i=0; i<testArray.count; i++) {
    let string: String = testArray[i]["name"] as! String
    newArray.append(string)
}
```

（Realmなどモバイル向けデータベースを使えば扱いやすくなるのだと思いますが、１０個程度しかデータがないので、ちょっとオーバースペックかなと）

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`map()`が登場するときがやってきました。以下のコードを、Playgroundで実行してみてください。

```
import UIKit

let webview0 = UIWindow()
let webview1 = UIWindow()
let webview2 = UIWindow()

let dic0: [String: AnyObject] = ["name": "yuichi", "string": "test1", "number": 2, "web": webview0]
let dic1: [String: AnyObject] = ["name": "kato", "string": "test2", "number": 5, "web": webview1]
let dic2: [String: AnyObject] = ["name": "max", "string": "test3", "number": 8, "web": webview2]

let testArray = [dic0, dic1, dic2]

let nameArray = testArray.map{$0["name"] as! String}

nameArray // ["yuichi", "kato", "max"]
```

`let nameArray = testArray.map{$0["name"] as! String}`

は省略形で、より省略していない形に戻すと、

```
let nameArray: [String] = testArray.map({dic: [String: AnyObject] -> String in
    return dic["name"] as! String
})
```

となります。
Arrayのメソッド`map()`は、配列のメンバーひとつひとつに対して、クロージャに定義した処理を行い、返り値を新規の配列のメンバーにするという作業をします。
Arrayには、ほかに`reduce()`、`filter()`などの便利なメソッドが用意されているので、一度お調べになるといいですよ。

Comment: すごい！こんな便利なメソッドがあったんですね。アドバイス頂いたとおり、reduce(), filter()等も調べて、使いこなせるようになりたいと思います。どうもありがとうございました。